# Matrix constructor curly brackets

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm developing a Matrix class for my purpose, I would ask about the constructor I would like to construct the matrix and initialize it using the curly brackets like this :

```
Matrix<double> M = {{1,2,3,},{4,5,6}};
```

My doubt is on the constructor.. here the code that I wrote! I would know if there is some more elegant (or in general better) way do doing so :

here the usable class with just this constructor .. and a usable main function

```
# include <iostream>

# include <initializer_list>
# include <iterator>




using namespace std;

template <typename data_type>
class Matrix {
    public:  

    constexpr Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<data_type>> rows) {

            size_t row = rows.size() ;

            auto il = *(rows.begin()); 
            size_t col = il.size();
            cout << row << ' ' << col << endl;


            size_t i=0;

            size_t n = row * col;

            cout << n << endl;;
            data = new data_type[ n ];
            i=0; 
            for(auto& row : rows )
                  for(auto & r : row){
                        data[i] = r ;
                        i++;
                  }
            for (i=0; i < n ; i++ ) 
                   cout << data[i] << endl;




    }

    private:

    data_type* data;

};





int main(){


      Matrix<int>  mat = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};


   return 0;   
}
```

thanks in advance for your precious support

Comment: Use std::vector instead of new[].

Comment: no for this case I want use the basic pointer ..

Comment: That’s a bad decision.

Comment: I know ! .. but is related to a compatibility with other code

Comment: @MarcoGhiani: That can only be true if the other code uses `delete[]`.

Comment: yes this is bthe reason ! Numerical recipes container use delete []